# No Uploads with RTE Image Upload?

Tags: file-uploads, rte

In EE 3.5.10 using the Image Upload button in the RTE toolbar, I can only choose existing images. There is no upload button.

Is this the way it is supposed to be?

Comment: are you sure the member group has upload rights to that directory

Comment: Yes. Logged in as a Super Admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the directory dropdown from "All" to the directory you're trying to upload to. Once you select it you should get the option to upload at the bottom.

[image]